# custom share url on ios iMessenger

Tags: ios, angular, sharekit

While sharing a custom url in my angular app through native share kit in iOs. The url shared is correct in all the apps like email and facebook while in iMessenger only the domain url is shared.
Tried on other applications it's working fine but on imessenger it's failing.
Please suggest any solution.

Comment: Please try a solution, get stuck and then ask, by posting what you tried.

Comment: @godhar thanks for advise, but like i said i have no idea why only for iMessenger its not working.
I already have solution which works fine for rest like sharing on gmail,whatsapp etc